# How to take the number field from a sequence of BigInteger in F#?

Tags: f#

Take this factorial sequence as an example:

```
factTake 5;;
val it : seq<System.Numerics.BigInteger> =
  seq [1 {IsEven = false;
          IsOne = true;
          IsPowerOfTwo = true;
          IsZero = false;
          Sign = 1;}; 2 {IsEven = true;
                         IsOne = false;
                         IsPowerOfTwo = true;
                         IsZero = false;
                         Sign = 1;}; 6 {IsEven = true;
                                        IsOne = false;
                                        IsPowerOfTwo = false;
                                        IsZero = false;
                                        Sign = 1;}; 24 {IsEven = true;
                                                        IsOne = false;
                                                        IsPowerOfTwo = false;
                                                        IsZero = false;
                                                        Sign = 1;}; ...]
```

How can I collect the numbers in the result into a list, like this:

```
[1; 2; 6; 24]
```

**Update**

Thanks for @Nicole A and @RCH's comment. The problem turns out to be simple:

```
factTake 8 |> Seq.toList |> printfn "%A"

[1; 2; 6; 24; 120; 720; 5040; 40320]
val it : unit = ()
```

This post on printfn from *F# for fun and profit* is also useful:
[Formatted text using printf](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/)!

Comment: BigIntegers are already 'numbers'. Do you want the seq to be a list, the BigIntegers to be truncated (to e.g. int64) or just the numbers printed without the BigIntegers internals?

Comment: @RCH I want the numbers printed without the BigIntergers internals.

Comment: @Nick I see you found out for yourself, good work.

Comment: @RCH Your comment is really a good hint. Thanks!

Comment: one of you should make this into an answer so we can close the question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we found out collectively:

```
factTake 8 |> Seq.toList |> printfn "%A"
```